# How do I find out which version of org-mode I am using?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I find out which version of org-mode I am using?

My current `init.el` is giving me errors relating to `org-babel-do-load-languages` and I've seen reference to a different variable  `org-babel-load-languages` defined in v7.01, but I don't know what version I am currently running.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can invoke org-version:

```
M-x org-version
```

This should give you the version information of currently loaded org-mode.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the package listing

```
M-x package-list-packages
```

Then find down the bottom which 'org' you are using. It maybe under status 'built-in' or 'installed', if you click on org then it will tell you the version.